# View 1 monitor in VNC session?

Tags: vnc, multi-monitor, x11vnc

I'm running Linux Mint 18 with `x11vnc` and the Nvidia drivers. My system is configured for one large desktop which spans 3 monitors (it was the default configuration).

When I create a VNC session using VNC Viewer (Mac) I receive the large extended desktop, creating a very slow refresh rate. Is there a way to attach just one display? How would I reconfigure the Nvidia driver and `x11vnc` to do this?

Comment: On the viewer side can you connect to pcName :0.1? :0 should be the default display to connect to and the .1 is the second (?) monitor.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc), it seems, the option `-clip` would seem to do what you want:

```
-clip WxH+X+Y

   Only show the sub-region of the full display that corresponds to the rectangle
   geometry with size WxH and offset +X+Y. The VNC display has size WxH (i.e. smaller
   than the full display). This also works for -id/-sid mode where the offset is
   relative to the upper left corner of the selected window. An example use of this
   option would be to split a large (e.g. Xinerama) display into two parts to be
   accessed via separate viewers by running a separate x11vnc on each part.

   Use  '-clip  xinerama0'  to clip to the first xinerama sub-screen (if xinerama is
   active). xinerama1 for the 2nd sub-screen, etc. This way you don't need to figure
   out the WxH+X+Y of the desired xinerama sub-screen. screens are sorted in increasing
   distance from the (0,0) origin (I.e. not the Xserver's order).
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `x11vnc` without any arguments and you should find  a list of all active displays, like this:

```
03/02/2022 12:05:13 Xinerama: sub-screen[0]  1920x1080+0+1440
03/02/2022 12:05:13 Xinerama: sub-screen[1]  2560x1440+0+0
03/02/2022 12:05:13 Xinerama: sub-screen[2]  2000x1200+1920+1440
```

As example: I want to only select `sub-screen[2]`, so I'll run `x11vnc -clip 2000x1200+1920+1440`